# Можно ли создавать свои REST запросы?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, rest, запрос

Возник глупый вопрос про типы запросов REST. Я понимаю, что эти методы общепринятые:

POST - создание.
PUT - замена целиком.
PATCH - редактирование.
DELETE - удаление.
и тд.

Однако могу ли я создавать свои собственные?

У меня есть функция которая вызывается через onclick и записывает id элемента:

```
function test(){
var element = document.getElementById(e);
var json = {};
    var bot_id = element.id
    
    var token = '{{csrf_token}}';
    json["id"]=bot_id
    
            $.ajax({
                headers: { "X-CSRFToken": token },
                url: window.location.pathname,
                type: 'SUNRISE',
                data: JSON.stringify({
                json
                })
            });}
```

и передает во views.py который выводит этот id на html страницу:

```
def test(request):
   if request.method == "SUNRISE":
       a=request.body
       stream = io.BytesIO(a)
       data = JSONParser().parse(stream)
       return render(request, "test.html", {"id": data["json"]['bot_id']})
```

В консоли выводит как стандартный запрос "SUNRISE /main/ HTTP/1.1" 200 14982 и переводит на html страницу с id.
Почему-то это работает? И можно ли это использовать? Обязательно ли использовать общепринятый метод для каких-то действий? (Например: Отправлять DELETE, но вместо удаления создавать новый объект.)

Comment: Дайте индексируемый заголовок вопросу

Comment: Например: Отправлять DELETE, но вместо удаления создавать новый объект. Так это можно и так сделать не изменяя названия метода. Просто при отправке delete обработать как post

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin то есть мне не обязательно придерживаться правил? Я могу отправлять PATCH и создавать нового юзера?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Метод - это просто последовательность из любых символов, кроме управляющих и разделителей. В RFC 2616, ссылку на который привели в соседнем ответе, явно указывается, что приведённые в нём методы - это всего лишь общеупотребительные методы, и что этот список может быть расширен.

То, как будет интерпретирован метод, и какие действия на стороне сервера он вызовет - зависит исключетельно от самого сервера. Какую логику напишите, так и будет.

Например, часто не реализуют отдельно методы PUT и PATCH, а ограничиваются только методом POST. Если он вызывается для несуществующего ресурса, то создаётся новый, а если для существующего - то редактируется.

Но, разумеется, не стоит совсем уж радикально отходить от общепринятых практик.

Comment: немного дополню. технически можно написать и свой сервер и придумать новый протокол. 
но если у нас HTTP, то надо использовать только стандартные методы, их формат запросов и ответов.
список может расширен только на уровне стандарта. 

я к тому, что может оно локально и работает, но любой разраб отклонит такой код, сказав переделывать.

а еще в последующем получится так, что за nginx из коробки оно не заработает "405 Method Not Allowed" надо прописывать в конфиги перечисление Allowed Methods.
какой-нибудь swagger и http client уже не подключишь, потому они там не реализованы и т.п

Answer (score 0):

Нет, методы запросов зафиксированы в спецификации HTTP: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-9.1.2.

Более того, это транспортный протокол, который находится на уровень ниже, чем ваша бизнес логика.

Comment: ..на уровень ниже

Comment: @ВадимАлександруь поправил, спс

Comment: @tcpack4 что-то я это плохо разумею. То есть если я выложу это на сервере человек не сможет отправлять эти запросы так же как у меня на локальном сервере?

Comment: Эх, всю свою жизнь HTTP был не транспортным, а прикладным протоколом, но потом пришли современные веб-разработчики и всё испортили :(